# Convert mp3 to flv

Tags: conversion, mp3, python, flv

I want to convert mp3 files to flv

Why it doesn't work?

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp3 -f flv -acodec libmp3 -ab 64 -ac 1 myfile.flv
ffmpeg version 0.7-rc1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 25 2011 02:37:46 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: 
  libavutil    50. 40. 1 / 50. 40. 1
  libavcodec   52.120. 0 / 52.120. 0
  libavformat  52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavdevice  52.  4. 0 / 52.  4. 0
  libavfilter   1. 77. 0 /  1. 77. 0
  libswscale    0. 13. 0 /  0. 13. 0
[NULL @ 0xa1c7600] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 0xa1c7600] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16)
[mp3 @ 0xa1c7600] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
1.mp3: could not find codec parameters
```

Comment: its a python script that will start the ffmpeg process via subprocess.Popen

Comment: Ah.. I'd suggest to tag or label this question also to 'python' so that python programmers will notice it more...

Comment: ok, i did it, but i dont know, its more a ffmpeg and not a python problem

Comment: Have you got all the codecs installed?

Answer (score 1):

This page:

http://heardspace.sulehosting.co.za/2007/09/converting-mp3-to-flv-with-ffmpeg/

suggests that you're passing the right arguments.

This page:

https://roundup.libav.org/issue564

suggests that your MP3 file might start with a truncated AC3 frame, or in some other way be different. I also find no search results for "Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!", so my guess is that you've got an MP3 file that is different, or that your FFmpeg is new and buggy. Try the conversion with an MP3 file you haven't produced.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a 160 bit rate mp3 to flv, I used this code (in Windows XP SP3) successfully:

`ffmpeg -y -i FILE1.mp3 -f flv -acodec libmp3lame -ab 160k -ac 1 FILE1.flv`

**Please note:** while I realize this is an old post, it's one of the first to show up when using Google Search with this parameter: "ffmpeg converting mp3 to flv".